# Haproxy "nbproc 2" high CPU

Tags: haproxy

I had a 95% CPU usage with a single haproxy process, so I switched to `nbproc 2`.

I have a two frontends and two backends; I pinned 1 frontend and 1 backend to process 1, and pinned the remaining two to process 2. I expected the load on the CPU cores to be distributed based on the load of the frontend/backend groups, however, now I have two haproxy processes, one using 20% CPU, the other still using 95% CPU. Why is that the case?

I am not yet dropping connections, but I will be as I start using even more CPU on that one thread.

Configuration is as follows:

```
global
    nbproc 2
    maxconn 150000
    user root # haproxy
    group root # haproxy
    daemon
    stats socket /var/run/haproxy.sock group haproxy mode 775

defaults
    mode tcp
    timeout connect 5000ms
    timeout client 130s
    timeout server 130s

frontend http-in
    bind-process 2
    bind *:80
    mode http
    maxconn 40000

    acl host_typea hdr(host) -i typea.example.com
    acl host_typeb hdr(host) -i www.example.com

    use_backend typea-backend if host_typea
    use_backend typeb-backend if host_typeb

    default_backend typeb-backend

frontend proxy-customers-frontend
    bind-process 1
    bind *:20000
    maxconn 10000
    option httpclose
    mode http
    log global
    acl host_typec hdr(proxy-authorization) -m len gt 80
    use_backend typec-backend if host_typec

    default_backend typed-backend

backend typea-backend
    bind-process 2
    mode http
    balance url_param ip check_post

    server localhost-30000 127.0.0.1:30000 check
    server localhost-30001 127.0.0.1:30001 check
    server localhost-30002 127.0.0.1:30002 check
    server localhost-30003 127.0.0.1:30003 check
    server localhost-30004 127.0.0.1:30004 check
    server localhost-30005 127.0.0.1:30005 check
    server localhost-30006 127.0.0.1:30006 check
    server localhost-30007 127.0.0.1:30007 check

backend typeb-backend
    bind-process 2
    mode http
    option forwardfor
    server localhost-81 127.0.0.1:81 check

backend typec-backend
    bind-process 1
    mode http
    server localhost-19999 127.0.0.1:19999 check

backend typed-backend
    bind-process 1
    mode http

    server localhost-20001 127.0.0.1:20001 check
    server localhost-20002 127.0.0.1:20002 check
    server localhost-20003 127.0.0.1:20003 check
    server localhost-20004 127.0.0.1:20004 check
    server localhost-20005 127.0.0.1:20005 check
    server localhost-20006 127.0.0.1:20006 check
    server localhost-20007 127.0.0.1:20007 check
    server localhost-20008 127.0.0.1:20008 check
```

Comment: Seeing your config might help...

Comment: @GregL Added my current configuration.

Answer (score 2):

I've just started down a similar road with enabling multiple processes for haproxy.  Based on the information [here](https://blog.codeship.com/performance-tuning-haproxy/), it appears that the default behavior of the Linux kernel is for the processes to inherit CPU affinity from the parent, which would default to the same CPU.  I believe you will see a difference if you map each process to a specific CPU with cpu-map:

```
nbproc 2
cpu-map 1 0
cpu-map 2 1
```